# jQuery form plugin: issues with radio button on serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a simple form:

```
<form class="dataform" method="post" id="settings" action="/">
    <input type="radio" name="shareSetting" value="n"/>
    <input type="radio" name="shareSetting" value="y"/>
    <input type="button" name="sendSettings" value="Store"
        class="btn" onClick="javascript:sendSettings();" />
</form>
```

And the following JavaScript code:

```
function sendSettings() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $("form#settings").serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        url: '?settings=store',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#divSettings').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

This works perfectly fine in Firefox (3.6 and 4B), Chrome 10, Opera 11, Safari 5 but - you guessed it - not in IE 8.

**IE doesn't send the content of the radio button, although a value is selected in the browser. It seems that the `$("form#settings")` lookup fails in IE for unknown reasons.**

Please let me know if any of you ran into the same issue and how you fixed it.

Many thanks!

Comment: i think your error must be happening when none of the radio buttons are clicked. Am i correct??

Comment: no, the error occurs even though one of the radio buttons is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the structure (seems like a bug in IE to me). Initially I had:

```
<p> / <form> / <dl> / as listed in the question
```

The issue was gone as soon as I changed the HTML to:

```
<form> / <p> / <dl> / as listed in the question
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ybFRu/1/

check this this works fine in ie,7, ie8

Comment: Thank you, that worked but wasn't a feasible solution for me because it the entire system works in a different way.